# Why doesn't Apache log startup errors on Windows?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

I'm using Zend Server CE on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, and I'm trying to activate HTTPS with a self-signed certificate.

I uncommented this line in httpd.conf:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

I copied my server.crt and server.key to the conf directory, and then tried to restart Apache via the Apache Monitor. But then got a pop-up message saying:

> The requested operation has failed!

I then headed to logs/error.log, but the most recent entry is more than 1 hour old and does not match the current problem at all.

**Why isn't the cause of the error logged in error.log?** Where should I look for it instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem simply by typing `httpd` on the Windows command line:

```
c:\>httpd
Syntax error on line 56 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
SSLSessionCache: Invalid argument: size has to be >= 8192 bytes
```

Still wondering *why this is not logged to error.log*, but at least I now have a way to know what's wrong.